# You can wrap $() around an array of DOM elements, or around a jQuery object, but not around an array of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

<strike>Not really sure how to phrase this question so it's generic enough.  (and will rephrase, after I know what I'm asking).  The problem, I believe deals with variables in a JQuery `.find()` function.</strike>

Problem: you can wrap `$()` around an array of DOM elements, or around a jQuery object, but not around an array of jQuery objects

<strike>The best I can do, at this time, is provide an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/theoryshaw/JvFR4/)</strike>

The problem code in the previous fiddle, is here:

```
////////////////Neither of the following works////////////////
//nodelevel = nodesWithMinuses.find('div.node.level' + levelnumber);
  nodelevel = $(nodesWithMinuses).find('div.node.level' + levelnumber);
////////////////Neither of the previous works////////////////
```

Comment: *What* problem? If you don't know what you're asking, don't ask.

Comment: Before I let guests visit my house, I tidy it up a bit to make sure it looks reasonably nice. Why do people think that it should be any different for their code?

Comment: @zzzzBov LOL I've been following you for the past 25 minutes and almost all of your comments have been hostile to condescending. I'd flag them if they weren't so funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apparently](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) you can wrap `$()` around an array of DOM elements, or around a jQuery object, but not around an array of jQuery objects.

Try changing this line:

```
var nodeWithMinus = thisplusminus.parent().parent();
```

to this:

```
var nodeWithMinus = thisplusminus.parent().parent()[0];
```

This will extract the DOM element and turn `nodesWithMinuses` into an array of DOM elements.

Comment: bingo! Man... would have been searching for days on that one...not very obvious. If you don't mind... going to use your answer to rephrase question. Thanks Much.

Comment: +1 "Apparently you can wrap $() around an array of DOM elements" -- interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `nodesWithMinuses` is an array of jQuery objects. You cannot apply jQuery method to anything else then a jQuery object. You have 2 options : either you declare `nodesWithMinuses` as a jQuery object and add objects to it via the `add` method :

```
var nodesWithMinuses = $();
//...
nodesWithMinuses.add(element);
// instead of nodesWithMinuses.push(element);
```

either find a way to convert the array to a jQuery object :

```
$($.map(nodesWithMinuses,function(el,i){return el.get(0)})).find('div.node.level' + levelnumber);
```

or traverse the array and search for the element in each object at a time :

```
var result = $();
$.each(nodesWithMinuses,function(i,el){
    result.add(nodesWithMinuses.find('div.node.level' + levelnumber));
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `nodeWithMinuses` is an array but you're trying to wrap it in the jQuery function. That doesn't work on arrays. Using a variable in jQuery's `find` function is fine.